# Move everything in a Storyboard view into a scroll view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a view (show below) in my storyboard. When I am typing in the stuff on the bottom the keyboard covers up what I am typing. The easiest way (I believe) to solve this would be to put everything in the view in a `UIScrollView`.

Is there an easy way to move everything in that view into a scroll view? Or if you believe there is a better way to do this what is it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue I did something slightly similar to @paulvs to move all of the text fields into the scroll view first I made a new view controller and put a scroll view in it. Then I selected all of the text fields using `command` on the keyboard and copy-pasted them into the scroll view.

Not sure if this is the most elegant way to make sure the user can see the text boxes at the bottom but it seems to have worked to move the text fields.

Answer (score 7):

For putting everything in scrollview just select all your views (hold shift and click on every view) and go to editor in toolbar of xcode select option 'Embed In', select scroll view and you are done.

Comment: When I click on the view in the screenshot above and go to editor the 'In scroll view' button is grayed out. How do I fix that?

Comment: You must also be selecting the superview on which your views are lying, just select your textfields, imageview and signup button, then scrollview option will not be grayed out.